# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

Estou com esse problema, o código mostra este erro:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\www\crud-master\formulario.php on line 33

**MODELS:**

```
<?php

try {

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=CRUD_DATA', 'root', 'root');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "LOG de Erro {$e}";
}      

/*
    === Aqui temos uma conexao tipo SINGLETON, que garente que teremos apenas uma conexao durante todo o processo.
 *      Isso evita que muitas conexoes sejam abertas ocassionando lentidao no sistema
 */
```

**formulario.php**

```
<?php
require('./conn/conexao_PDO.php');


if ($_GET) {

    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM pessoas WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}");

    if ($sql !== false) {
        //imprima
        foreach ($sql as $row) {

        }
    }
} elseif ($_POST) {
    $sql = "UPDATE pessoas set nome = '{$_POST['nome']}', email = '{$_POST['email']}', telefone = '{$_POST['telefone']}', endereco = '{$_POST['endereco']}'";
    $query = $pdo->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pessoas where id = {$_POST['id']}";

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $data = $query->fetch_assoc();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <?php require ('./header.php'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>ID:<?php echo $row['id']?></h2>
            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="formulario.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="nome">Nome:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']?>">

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Como te lhamas ??" value="<?php echo $row['nome']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Qual é o email pra enviar nudes ?" value="<?php echo $row['email']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="telefone" placeholder="Numero do zap zap ?" value="<?php echo $row['telefone'];?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endereco" placeholder="Endereço para os Presentes" value="<?php echo $row['endereco']?>">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">SALVAR ALTERAÇÃO</button>
                        <a href="index.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Voltar</button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Variável indefinida $row. Você atribui os valores do fetch() a **$data e não $row**.Você tem que mudar o nome da sua variável.

Answer (score 1):

Você está com uma variável indefinida chamada `$row`.

O que acontece é que você atribui os valores do `fetch()` a variável `$data` e depois chama por uma variável que não foi criada, `$row`. Você tem que mudar o nome da sua variável, ou na hora do `fetch()`:

```
$data = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

para isso:

```
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Ou mudar todos os:

```
<?php echo $row['campo']?>
```

para isso:

```
<?php echo $data['campo']?>
```

Comment: Eu mudei para $row = $query->fetch_assoc();, mais o erro continua.

Comment: Queria perguntar, qual a lógica do if($_GET), if($_POST)? Porque você verifica se eles são verdadeiros, então nem dá para saber em qual vai entrar. Você sabe em qual dos ifs vai entrar? @MichelSpirlandeli

Comment: Dependendo, pode ser que entre no $_GET e nesse if não está programado $row = $query->fetch_assoc();. Perto de  if ($sql !== false) {
        //imprima
        foreach ($sql as $row) {

Comment: Então não consegui resolver isso acabei mudando td meu codigo,mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Tente tirar o `['id']` do `$row` porque no

```
foreach($sql as $row)
```

`$row` irá receber a última propriedade da array. Então `$row` ficará uma string

Comment: Reveja sua resposta. Não condiz nada com a pergunta.